# how does a component gets props from a reducer in redux(how does the connect function work)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

*That's a question for personal learning because I am struggling to learn this part from online resources*
I am creating a component that gets its props from a reducer, and I know that the store and actions are the things that link those props to the requested component but I don't understand how this happens(via javascript)

here's the songsReducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { selectSong } from '../actions';

const songsReducer = () =>{
    return [
{title:'myImmortal',duration:'4:05'},
{title:'BringMeToLife',duration:'2:05'},
{title:'IWantItThatWay',duration:'2:35'},
{title:'YourStar',duration:'4:35'},
    ]
}
const selectedSongReducer = (selectedSong=null,action) =>{
if(action.type==='SONG_SELECTED'){
    return action.payload;
}
return selectedSong;
}

export default combineReducers({
    songs: songsReducer,
    selectedSong:selectedSongReducer
})
```

it should give these props to the SongList.js component via the connect function as in this syntax:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class SongList extends React.Component{
render(){
    return <div>SongList</div>
}
}

const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{

console.log(state)
return {songs:state.songs}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SongList);
```

In 'mapStateToProps' when we logged state to the console it was holding the array 'songs' resulting from 'songsReducer' and I didn't understand how that javascript syntax could give that result.

can someone help me learn more about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connect` function simply takes your redux state and injects it to the component's props. After it injects it, you could easily access it on the props object. So, in your case, you would access the songs state like this:

```js
this.props.songs
```

Comment: I quite get this part, the part I am struggling with is how the function mapStateToProps got the state argument as value from somewhere and I don't what's that 'somewhere'

Comment: const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{

console.log(state)
return {songs:state.songs}
}

Comment: how did 'state' in that function get a value? from where?

Comment: Okay so what happens is that when you call the connect function it goes to the nearest `Provider` in the component tree, takes the store that was provided there and puts it as the state.
You could read more about how it works in this article, it seems like it explains it really good:
https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/

Comment: Hi, I'm a Redux maintainer and author of React-Redux v7.  I would actually recommend reading my post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/), my talk [A Deep Dive into React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/), and the ["UI and React" page](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react) in the Redux docs "Redux Fundamentals" tutorial.